# need advice normalizing userpassword/access database tables

Tags: sql, normalization

I'm trying to normalize a database to hold usernames and passwords, as well as what web pages particular users have access to. This is what I started with for the simplicity's sake but I think the 'useraccess' table violates the first rule of normalization according to the 2 books I have...

```
userpassword table(userid,username,userpassword)
useraccess table(userid, accesstopage0,accesstopage1,accesstopage2,accesstopage3)
```

**Obviously the useraccess table is in danger of getting out of hand. My question is...what is the best way to fix this problem? So far, this is what I have come up with to replace the useraccess table**, but I would like some advice on if there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
useraccess(userid,useridsequence,pageid)
pages(pageid,pagename)
```

So an example would be...

```
userpassword table(userid,username,userpassword)
0, useralpha, jinx
1, userbravo, binx
2, usercharlie, jabber
```

Then using userid and useridsequence as a compound key to maintain integrity...

```
useraccess table(userid, useridsequence, pageid)
0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1
0, 2, 2
1, 0, 3
2, 0, 1
2, 1, 2

pages table(pageid,pagename)
0, page0.php
1, page1.php
2, page2.php
3, page3.php
```

All of this seems way more complicated than it needs to be is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what's the sequence id for? all you really need for the join is the userid and pageid, though you might consider an artificial pk for ease in managing the relationship.

Comment: As an aside, I hope you're really going to store a [salted (and peppered) hash](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough) rather than the actual passwords in that table.

Comment: With sequence id+userid you get a unique row. I'm using a SHA512 hash algorithm plus salting for the passwords. I didn't say that because this is more about sql than security.

Comment: You get the same thing from a uniqueness constraint on userid/pageid.  In fact, a unique index on these two columns in this table would be a really good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a userpermissions table which represents a many to many join between users and pages.

This table could also contain an attribute defining the level of permission for that page.

If your users largely have the same permissions then you could introduce the idea of roles - guest, member, admin, etc, and map users to roles, and then roles to permissions.

Additionaly please note that you should be salting and hashing your passwords to prevent anyone who compromises your application from gaining valuable credentials.